# Quarkus Extension - Remove a class from dependent library or replace part of a class

Tags: quarkus

Within a custom Quarkus extension I would like to integrate an existing java library that currently is not compatible to Quarkus.

Are there any examples for the following use cases:

- remove a java class from a dependency library (library is referenced as maven-dependency)- In this case I'll provide a compatible implementation within the runtime-module.
- replace specific parts of an existing class form a dependency library (e.g. a default implementation of an interface)

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you can use a `io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.RemovedResourceBuildItem` to have Quarkus essentially remove a class from a dependency.

For the second case, you'll likely need to use a `io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.BytecodeTransformerBuildItem` which lets you declare an ASM class transformer which can change a class in arbitrary ways.

If you are only looking to change the class for native mode, it's much easier to instead use `com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.TargetClass` and `com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.Substitute`.

Comment: perfect tip - will try it out according to this example - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/70074316e385e2f3c07c8058e376b76e007fbed2/extensions/jdbc/jdbc-oracle/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/jdbc/oracle/deployment/OracleMetadataOverrides.java#L120